# Are there any Final Cut Pro, Motion or Premiere plug-ins that allow insertion of PowerPoint or Keynote slides?

Tags: premiere, final-cut-pro-x, motion, plugins

I haven't found an easy way to splice a slide into a video. I can save the presentation to a QuickTime movie in Keynote, but I need to do this twice a week for a number of slides.

I'm recording a live evening lecture series that is shown at a number of sites the following day. Since the sites only have one projector, I need to give them a video feed that has both video of the speaker(s) and the slides.

I've been doing this manually, but it's an hour-long lecture that ends at 9 PM. I'm often up into the wee hours of the morning trying to get everything sorted and rendered and posted to Vimeo for a 6 AM first showing.

If you're doing something like this, please share your workflow.

Answer (score 1):

### If your show requires some level of postproduction, then:

1 Record the live video feed of the presenter's slideshow.  Don't just export the slides as a movie from Keynote.  Syncing slides manually will definitely keep you up into the wee hours of the morning, so don't do it.

2 Import the camera feed(s) of the speaker, any extra audio sources, and the slides, group them in a multicam clip, and sync them all together.  Again, for fastest postproduction turnaround, the more automated you can make the sync process, the earlier you get to go home.  Timecode based sync is the fastest, but most expensive.  A hand clap is free, but won't help you sync the slides to the speaker.  You've obviously already figured out how to do that manually, but finding one sync point per hour of footage is way better than doing it for x number of slides.

3 Once you've been through a couple of episodes of your show, and ironed out the kinks in look dev and process, save an extra copy of your project file and strip it of reference to any of the media you imported in step 2.  Leave everything else about this file alone; titles, intros/outros, etc. Use this file as a template for your show.  If your process involves complex file hierarchies, do the same with your file hierarchies: have a "template" project folder which includes your project files, working directories, output directories, stock graphics, etc.

4 Now, each time you do a new show, duplicate the template structure, rename it accordingly, populate it with your fresh content, fill in the blanks, and start over at #1.  As you work through more iterations, tweak the template files to incorporate as much repetition as you can automate.  You might want to pick up a scripting language or two, maybe look into some machine vision algorithms, keep an eye on github. Automate anything that gives you carpel tunnel.  Reschedule every progress bar you see to a time when you won't see it.

### But if you don't need to make any kind of postproduction edit, then the answer's simple: Don't.

You've now left the world of digital film production and entered the land of broadcast.  To pursue this avenue, you'll need to be able to mix and switch all of your live a/v, and record or OTT the program.  Your requirements are minimally a $100-ish converter box and a laptop, but again, the more money you can throw at it, the better.  Blackmagic ultra studio mini recorder or whatever Aja's equivalent product is called would get you started.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. I'm already doing what you've suggested, unfortunately. There's minimal budget (actually, there is no budget). Recording the projection of the slide show gives extremely poor production values...that's why I'm looking for the plug-in

Comment: I find it difficult to believe that everyone who needs to insert slides into a video presentation follows such a cumbersome, time-consuming process.

Comment: Why would recording the projection give you quality less than what you're already willing to project in the first place?  It should be a 1:1 copy.

Comment: Everyone thinks video production is easier than it is.  The truth is that it's like any other design process: the more time and money you can put into it, the better the results.  How is that surprising?

Comment: Panning a camera to show the projection screen and back is not aesthetically pleasing. We're all volunteer and are trying to make the best of space and equipment that is available. Even if we had the funds to purchase equipment at each site, it needs to be something we can use without tampering with the facility's equipment too much. A plug-in would allow us to do everything in software.

Comment: I don't mean point the camera at the screen, I mean capture the  presentation signal before it gets to the screen. Either use screen recording software on the presentation laptop, or insert a recording device in the signal chain. What, exactly do you expect a plug-in to do for you that isn't built in to the basic functionality of an NLE, anyway? "Splicing" falls pretty squarely under the domain of the "E" part. Also, I never said anything about purchasing equipment at multiple sites.

Comment: There are about 60 slides per session. I already note when the slides are shown by slide number and approximate time code. I would like to point at the PPT or Keynote file, scrub to the correct timecode and pop the correct slide in place. Next time code/next slide. I can't go fooling around with the facility's equipment.

Comment: So, first, Keynote and PowerPoint are direct competitors with proprietary formats; you’re unlikely to find any plugin designed to work with both.  At the same time, it’s also unlikely that you can force all of your presenters to use one or the other, exclusively.  But your bigger problem is that neither software records a timestamp when the presenter clicks “next slide.”  Which is why, like you said, you note "approximate" time code…

Comment: …Without an exact time to go by, a computer would need to do statistic analysis of the video image to guess transition times.  Resolve's Scene Cut Detection does this, but it generates so many false positives that you’re better off doing it by hand.  Nevermind the difficulty of scripting integration with EITHER slideshow app, you’d have to record the video feed of the slides ANYWAY, which you say you can’t do.

Comment: The best tools to work with when all you have are approximate time code are the ones that are already built into the NLE.

Comment: That's a good point. It would be good if we could automate getting the timecode from Keynote/PowerPoint.

Comment: I think you're over-complicating things. I don't need millisecond-accurate cuts to the slides. And considering that I can load PPT into Keynote, I only care about Keynote.

Comment: Actually, that gives me an idea of how to do this with Automator.

Comment: I'll be interested to see what you come up with.  Don't forget you can always answer your own question here.